# R: dplyr: how to use last, first, nth correct in a SQL-database?

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

I trying to use `last`/`first` or `nth` in a mutate step in a PostgreSQL-database.

If the data is in-memory everything is fine:

```
library("dplyr")
batting <- select(tbl_df(Batting), playerID, yearID, teamID, G, AB:H) 
batting <- group_by(batting, yearID)
batting <- mutate(batting, G2 = last(G))
```

Unfortunately I don't have a locale database on my computer, so this is the same code for a dataset stored in a PostgreSQL-DB:

```
library("dplyr")
mytab <- tbl(src_postgres(dbname, host, port, user, password), "catalog")
mytab <- group_by(mytab, catalog_id)
mytab<- mutate(mytab, curr2 = last(currency))
mytab
```

*RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  function first_value() does not exist*

```
mytab$query
```

*SELECT "catalog_id", "currency", "skonto", FIRST_VALUE() OVER (PARTITION BY "catalog_id") AS "curr2" FROM "catalog"*

In my opinion the query should be:

*SELECT "catalog_id", "currency", "skonto", FIRST_VALUE(**currency**) OVER (PARTITION BY "catalog_id") AS "curr2" FROM "catalog"*

Comment: Can you please file a bug on github?

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/531

Comment: @fc9.30, can you confirm whether this has been resolved with dplyr version 0.3.+? If so, you can post (and accept) an answer to that extent.